# Extracting data from XML into dictionary (1 line as key, next line as item)

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have a `XML` file with a header of summary information and a main data table after.  I've got the main data table out and into a `pd.df`, but now I want to extract parts of the header information into a dictionary.

**Example of `XML` file:**

```
<Workbook>
 <Worksheet>
  <Tables>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableTitle" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Administrative Data</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">B013</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Title</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">Mr</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Last Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">Data</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">First Name</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">Test</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row/>
   <Row/>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableTitle" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Biological and Medical Baseline Data</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Height</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">176 cm</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterName" ss:MergeAcross="1"><Data ss:Type="String">Weight</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="HeadTableParameterValue" ss:MergeAcross="7"><Data ss:Type="String">56.9 kg</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Tables>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

What I want to be able to do is extract the data in the 'Administrative Data' section to a dictionary with the first 'cell' value as the key (if I can remove the spaces that would be awesome), and the second 'cell' value as the item.  This then needs to be repeated so the data in the 'Biological and Medical Baseline Data' is held in a separate dictionary. Dictionary names can be whatever (e.g. 'subject' and 'biomed')

**Current code to parse the `XML` file and access the tags:**

```
from lxml import etree

f_path = 'data store/cortex_full.xml'  # enter path of xml file

# open and parse xml file
with open(f_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # set encoding to utf-8 for mac
    root = etree.parse(f)

namespaces = {'o': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office',
              'x': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel',
              'ss': 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'}


ws = root.xpath('/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet', namespaces=namespaces)
if len(ws) > 0:
    tables = ws[0].xpath('./ss:Table', namespaces=namespaces)
    if len(tables) > 0:
        rows = tables[0].xpath('./ss:Row', namespaces=namespaces)
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell/ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this? If a dictionary is not optional, also happy to work with other suggestions.

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup to parse XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare the below well before

```
subject={}
bio={}
d=None  #If this doesn't work then use d={}
```

And consider replacing

```
for row in rows:
   cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell/ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)
```

with

```
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.xpath('./ss:Cell', namespaces=namespaces)
            if(len(cells)==2):
              key=None
              item=None
              for cell in cells:
                if(cell.attrib['{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}StyleID']=="HeadTableParameterName"):
                  key=cell.xpath('./ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text.strip()
                else:
                  item=cell.xpath('./ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text.strip()
              if(not(key==None or item==None)):
                d[key]=item
            elif len(cells)==1:
              if(cells[0].attrib['{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}StyleID']=='HeadTableTitle'):
                if(cells[0].xpath('./ss:Data', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text=='Biological and Medical Baseline Data'):
                  d=bio
                else:
                  d=subject
print(bio)
print(subject)
```

Although not necessary I've put in some checks just to give an idea, but you can extend the checks to make it more robust.

Also I've a working version [here](https://repl.it/LrX8/1).

Comment: Sorry I probably did explain that very well.  The XML file has separate 'sections' when it's opened in Excel, the first section is titled `Administrative Data` and the second `Biological and Medical Baseline Data` - I don't want to keep either of these 'titles', but have separate dictionaries for the two sections - so anything under the `Admin` section goes into the `subject` dictionary and under the `biological` section goes into the `biomedical` dictionary.

Comment: Thank! I'll work through to try and understand whats going on. Although it works in your link, I'm getting a `KeyError: 'ss:StyleID:` on the `if(cells[0].attrib['ss:StyleID']=='HeadTableTitle'):` line on the actual file

Comment: Can you do a `print(cells[0].attrib)`. This should print a dictionary. You can use the same key from there.

Comment: I think it's got to do with the namespace. It may work if you remove `ss:`

Comment: for `print(cells[0].attrib)` output is `{'{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}StyleID': 'HeadTableTitle', '{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}MergeAcross': '1'}` given `ss` was set to the `urn` in the original code this should have carried - removing `ss:` caused same error

Comment: `cells[0].xpath('./@ss:StyleID', namespaces=namespaces)[0]`  instead of `cells[0].attribs['ss:StyleID']`

Comment: New error this time `TypeError: 'lxml.etree._Attrib' object is not callable`.

Comment: Remove the index `[0]`. Not sure though.

Comment: Same error.  I will keep playing around. But for now grand final of the footy is on (aussie rules)!!!!!! Cheers for your help.

Comment: `cells[0].xpath('./@ss:StyleID', namespaces=namespaces)[0]` should work https://repl.it/LrX8/2

Comment: You could be getting not callable because you might've used `(0)` instead of `[0]`

Comment: Still getting the same `not callable` error. I will post a new question asking about testing a tags attribute setting, see what other users might have to say on the issue.

Comment: needed to use the full path for the namespace `'{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}StyleID` rather than just `ss:`